# Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default(...)(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, webpack

I want to integrate jquery and bootstrap cdn in my vuejs web app.

But the error `jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default(...)(...).modal is not a function` keeps throwing.

Here is my code.

```js
mounted () {
    let scripts = [
      'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
      'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    ]
    scripts.forEach(script => {
      let tag = document.createElement('script')
      tag.setAttribute('src', script)
      document.head.appendChild(tag)
    });
}
```